# Is there a reputation level where the identity of down-voters is revealed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Is down voting open to scrutiny at any level?

Comment: Nope. Never. Sorry.

Comment: To be clear - down-voting is always totally anonymous with no requirement at any level to explain the reason?

Comment: OK, I've been reading the related questions - it's all about the the language and the usage, no trouble!

Comment: I believe up- and downvoting is anonymous across all of StackExchange; not even moderators can see who has voted which way, and perhaps not many of the staff either.

Comment: May I ask why you think it's important to know who the down voters are? Is it very different from needing to know who the up voters are? This has always fascinated me.

Comment: @medica While I agree hay voting, both up and down, should forever remain anonymous, and the identity of the downvoters is not relevant to the poster, the argument that upvotes and downvotes are perfectly symmetric & anything required or desired of one should immediately be demanded of the other has always rung a bit hollow for me. Upvotes say "this argument is correct; on point; I agree with it; ***it needn't be changed***". What else could be said? Downvotes say "this argument is *incorrect*; it is *off point*;  I *disagree* with it; ***it needs to be changed***". Ok, fine: **changed how**?

Comment: I think it is good that up- and down- voting are anonymous.  It's all about language and usage after all.  But I agree with @DanBron - whereas an up-vote needs no explanation, a down-vote does.  What is it that you are down voting?  A down vote without (anonymous) explanation is not constructive or helpful to anyone.

Comment: @DanBron - point taken, if that's really all the OP wants to know, but that's not usually the case. The OP most often wants to argue their point, not improve their answer, which is very tedious. Not everyone has to agree with an OP. If people have the right to anonymously agree, people have an **equal** right to anonymously disagree. There's nothing virtuous in demanding to know who the down voter is, and that mindset makes it next to impossible to comment on a down voted answer without being met with the OP's animus. Your argument overlooks this fact.

Comment: @Dan - neither is knowing the down voter's identity. You might want the down voter's reasons, but that's not what you asked for. And that, to me, is revealing.

Comment: @medica I agree with everything you're saying. My point is, I wish everyone who responded to the endless demands for non-anonymous downvotes advanced *those* arguments, rather than the spurious and easily-dismissed argument "well, why don't you ask for the identity of *upvoters*, then?". That's nothing more than a red herring, and because it's such an obvious red herring, I think it hurts the credibility of any valid and substantive arguments made thereafter. I wish we'd just do away with it altogether.

Comment: @medica my OP did NOT ask for identity at all.  My second, follow-up question was seeking clarification that I simply did not know (and asked about both identity AND providing reasons for your up/down vote).  I have made it clear that I am **entirely** happy with anonymity.  Why do you persist in using that uncontested argument as a shield to avoid explaining what good reasons  there may be for not asking down voters to explain their actions?

Comment: @Dan Medica did offer (embedded in a larger context) reasons for not *requiring* (that is, systematically enforcing) downvoters to explain their actions. She said: "*The OP most often wants to argue their point, not improve their answer, which is tedious*" and "*[Would] make it impossible to comment on a DVed answer without being met with the OP's animus*" (the implication of the latter being "*... even if I, the commentor, didn't personally doenvote, because systematically tying downvotes to comments makes it looks like every comment came from a downvoter*").

Comment: @Dan Anyway, your question is perfectly logical and reasonable; it's legitimate. The exasperation you're hearing from us simply stems from the fact that you're not the first person to ask. This is a very, very common question (*because* it is logical, reasonable, and legitimate). It's been covered many, many times before. And the conclusion, the consensus, is that the pros of anonymous, comment-free downvotes outweigh the cons of permitting them. If you stick around long enough, my bet is you'll come to agree with that decision. I know I did.

Comment: @DanBron - We keep that red herring because it's not offensive to the OP. However, saying, in effect: you only want to argue that the DVer is wrong/you want them to prove their point/you want to revenge down vote/you want to harass them/etc. will be met with more of the same. Anyway, I think we're in agreement otherwise.

Comment: @DanBron thank's for your comments.  I've been mulling over especially "...the pros of anonymous, comment-free downvotes outweigh the cons of permitting them...".  I'm pretty new to this site but I do understand that it attracts all sorts and that there are 'standards', not least for experienced users, with their own ideas of what EL&U can and should be.  I'm struck by the dismissal of down-voters being required to post (even anonymously) a reason for their action -"... OP most often wants to argue their point ... which is tedious".  Aren't we all making points (supported by evidence)?

Comment: @Dan I think the point of contention here is *permit* vs *require* comments on posts you downvote. The system already *permits* this, of course, and I encourage you to exercise that choice frequently over the next month or two, say, to learn why the system doesn't *require* downvoters to comment. The short story is you'll find, in most cases, that the poster is willing to put enormous amounts of effort into anything *except* improving his post along whatever lines you suggest (read: he'll spend *hours* telling you why you're wrong, but not than *minutes* to edit his post). It's enervating.

Comment: @Dan It would also be worth your while to go to [Meta.SE] and do a question search for people proposing this and related features. Each request has been declined (obviously, as we still don't have the feature), but the comments and answers explaining why not can be very enlightening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*While the intent of the question may have been to ask about mandatory commenting on casting a downvote, it actually asks a different question to which an answer might be useful.*

**Yes. Downvoting is open to scrutiny** but only to Community Managers† and Stack Exchange staff†. There is no reputation level which allows access to voter identity.

Moderators have some limited tools to examine vote patterns, but can’t see who cast which individual votes. Suspicious vote patterns are submitted to CMs for detailed investigation.

Voting is never truly anonymous, or rep lost with downvotes on answers which are subsequently deleted could never be refunded. There’s also a nightly job which examines voting and can invalidate certain votes (such as obvious revenge downvoting) automatically. The effect of revenge downvoting, and that it was done, can be seen by anyone; but only the auto job and CMs know who did it.

---

† Community Managers’ and staffers’ contributions on the site are identified with a diamond as if they were moderators (which they are) but they are not listed with the [site-elected moderators](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). [Further reading](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: My intent was to understand better how the site works.  Thanks to your answer I do now. Fascinating.